# A sword named lark?

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to remember the name of a book I read back in the 1980's about a guy who carried a singing sword named Lark.

**Some additional details:**

- It was quest style and I feel like it was written by a sci-fi author of renown - maybe Poul Anderson or someone in his era.
- I seem to recall either from the cover or description that the sword was a straight sword that came to a two side point like the tip of a narrow triangle and the guard was circular/semi globe. It was light gray in color.

**Does anyone remember this story or sword?**

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the only "singing sword" I can think of belonged to Prince Valiant in the stories of King Arthur and the Knights of the Round Table.

Comment: In _Light Fantastic_ by Terry Pratchett there's a singing sword named Kring owned by Hrun the Barbarian. [LSpace.org](http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Kring) describes it as being inspired the sword [Stormbringer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormbringer) which appeared in a number of Michael Moorcock's books. So singing swords are a fantasy staple not just a poetic device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is actually the *[Saga of Thorgrim](https://www.nobleknight.com/ProductDetail.asp_Q_ProductID_E_2147590231_A_InventoryID_E_0_A_ProductLineID_E_-169450278_A_ManufacturerID_E_979136733_A_CategoryID_E_16_A_GenreID_E_)*, by Gerard Earl Bailey.

> There is a lay the Agelings sing: of Thorgrim the glacier-born, who
>   was outlawed strode the sea on cross-grained ships of war; **of Lark,
>   the blood-loud sword that led his quest for the Spaehelm that was to
>   be his destiny;** and of the Priestess Lysenoe who was his fate. All
>   this was when the world was new and men did not walk it alone. Here
>   then is that song... Sword of the Nurlingas.

The main character is a viking-type who carries a sword (named Lark) which is black or gray metal with a rounded guard. The sword didn't 'sing' as such, just vibrated and made a distinctive noise as it was used.

The [cover](https://www.nobleknight.com/ProductDetail.asp_Q_ProductID_E_2147590231_A_InventoryID_E_0_A_ProductLineID_E_-169450278_A_ManufacturerID_E_979136733_A_CategoryID_E_16_A_GenreID_E_) of the first book, *Sword of the Nurlingas*, shows the character holding up the sword.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the addition of the blurb!  So, for the cover, you find an image somewhere on the web, copy it to imgur, then put the link here?

Comment: Great to know that I wasn't misremembering everything - just the singing and the author... The image definitely is as I remembered!